# PyDrake AttributeError: 'MultibodyPlant_[float]' object has no attribute 'get_body_poses_output_port'

Tags: python, drake

In PyDrake I get AttributeError from this line: *body_pose_output_port = plant.get_body_poses_output_port()*

Error message:

> AttributeError: 'MultibodyPlant_[float]' object has no attribute 'get_body_poses_output_port'

Here is how I set up the plant:

```
plt_is_interactive = SetupMatplotlibBackend()

builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0001)
file_name = FindResource("models/robot.urdf")
robot_model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
file_name = FindResource("models/object.urdf")
object_model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)

plant.Finalize()
plant.set_name('robot')
```

What I don't understand is that getting state output in essentially the same way doesn't raise any errors, i.e.*state_output_port = plant.get_state_output_port(robot_model)* behaves as expected and returns the correct port.

What's the difference in calling *get_body_poses_output_port()* vs. *get_state_output_port()* that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ method [MultibodyPlant::get_body_poses_output_port()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#aea0f8aca5f15e90f11e14602b3ba7068) is not bound in pydrake.

Comment: I will PR the binding.

Comment: The binding should now be available in drake master.  https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13229